# git filter repo - Python was not found - but it's installed

Tags: python, git, powershell, cmd, git-filter-repo

So I'm trying to use git filter-repo for the first time.
I've installed Python 3.9.
I try to run:
`git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than 100M`

Each time it fails:

- Git Bash: `git: 'filter-repo' is not a git command.`
- Powershell: `Python was not found;`
- CMD: `Python was not found;`

Any advice on what I'm missing please?

Comment: I realised my initial problem was not putting the file in the git core.
However what I'm now seeing is permissions denied to .lock files but I have no idea why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double-check the installation process on [`newren/git-filter-repo/INSTALL`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/e9e0308df1e9e792598b8e41d0086d7a785e9cc5/INSTALL.md)

You must make sure first (in a regular CMD) than `git-filter-repo` is in your `%PATH%`.
If you install it through `pip`, for instance, it should, since the [Python folder should be added to your PATH at Python3 installation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54934172/6309).

Once that `%PATH%` is correct (and you see `git-filter-repo` in it), then `git` will recognize the `filter-repo` command.

---

[As commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65626875/git-filter-repo-python-was-not-found-but-its-installed/65627307#comment118241569_65627307), there is now a [**`git-filter-repo` Homebrew formula**](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/git-filter-repo), which offers an easier installation process on a Mac.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Please see my initial comment on the post. I got it to recognise the command however it doesn't seem to change .lock files. I'm not sure why as I'm the creator of them.

Comment: @spsuk Check if another process is using one of those lock files. Try and see if the issue persists after a reboot, when hopefully less processes are active and less likely to keep an handle on those lock files.

Comment: If working on Mac there is now also a homebrew option I noticed after fiddling with Python2/3, pip2/3, pyenv and Git for too long. Painless:

https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/git-filter-repo

Comment: @user3271319 Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue: I put the `git-filter-repo` under `PATH` but I got the same 'Python not found' error, even though Python is installed and also under `PATH`.

I ended up solving this (or worked around it) by changing the she-bang (first comment line at the top) of the downloaded `git-fitler-repo` file. I changed it from

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

to

```
#!C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe
```

(the real Python path on my system) and now it works. It's surprising, because as far as I know Windows does not honor those she-bang lines.